# How to transform r data.table object based on function parameter

Tags: r, data.table, user-defined-functions

I would like to create r function which takes 2 parameters:

1. data.table object
2. instruction on how to add new columns to the data table. These new
   columns are a transformation of already existing columns.

**Without the wrapping function i could do:**

```
# load data.table library
library(data.table)
# the exsample data set
dt <- data.table(mtcars)

# adding some new columns
dt[, `:=`(disp_plus_hp = disp + hp,
          drat_plus_wt = drat + wt)]
```

**I know i can use `eval + parse` combo to solve my problem like this:**

```
# load the exsample data set
dt <- data.table(mtcars)

# character vector of length 1 specifying the transformation
column_transformation = '`:=`(disp_plus_hp = disp + hp,
                              drat_plus_wt = drat + wt)'

# define a function that takes data table and the above character
# to transform the data table
dt_transformer <- function(data_table, add_columns)
{
  data_table[, eval(parse(text = add_columns))]
}

# equivalent to dt[, `:=`(disp_plus_hp = disp + hp,drat_plus_wt = drat + wt)]
dt_transformer(data_table = dt, add_columns = column_transformation)
```

Now, there are two reasons i would like to improve the solution:

1. I do not like to have all the transformations specified in one
   string, because it then becomes very difficult to read (a list or a
   character vector with one element for each transformation would be
   nice)
2. I am not too excited about the use of parse function

Comment: don't use eval-parse but R language feature "computing on the language", it is precisely the use case where that feature is applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want is a function `dplyr::mutate` but with a `:=` operator. I recommend you to read the [non-standart evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) chapter from Advanced R book. The following function must be improved but basically does the job you want.

```
dtmutate <- function(dt, ...)
{
  exprs <- lazyeval::dots_capture(...)

  for (i in seq_along(exprs))
  {    
    col  <- names(exprs)[i]
    expr <- exprs[[i]]
    val  <- lazyeval::f_eval(expr, dt)
    dt[, (col) := val]
  }

  dt[]
  return(invisible())
}

library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = 1:10*2)
dtmutate(dt = dt, c = a+b, d = a*b)
dt
```